# Pass whatever is at current page ID to next page using a url

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, javascript, list-form

I want to pass my current ID dynamically when I click a hyperlink button from my `../dispform.aspx?ID=248` page to a second page `.../dispformManager.aspx?ID=@ID`

Does anyone have the correct code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to `dispform.aspx` page of list
2. Edit the page
3. Add content editor/script editor web part on page
4. Add below code in web part & Save/Stop editing the page.

```
<a id="redirectLink" href="">Click Here</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var itemId = getUrlParameter("ID");

        var aElement = $("a#redirectLink");
        aElement[0].href = "https://www.google.com?ID=" + itemId;
    });

    function getUrlParameter(param) {
        let url = window.location.href;
        if (!url) url = location.href;
        param = param.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\?&]" + param + "=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
        var results = regex.exec(url);
        return results == null ? null : results[1];
    }
</script>
```

You can replace the `aElement.href` & set the position of hyperlink on page as per your requirements.

Comment: So the first line would be?  <a id="redirectLink" href=".../dispformManager.aspx?ID=@ID">Click Here</a> or just leave it href="">

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking exactly? Follow the steps given in answer & copy paste the code as it is.

Comment: and aElement[0].href = "https://www.google.com?ID=" + itemId;  would be?  aElement[0].href = "../dispform.aspx?ID=248" + itemId; or do I have my urls reversed

Comment: Add the link where you want users to navigate to. I suppose, `aElement[0].href = ".../dispformManager.aspx?ID=" + itemId;`. Basically just generate the link as per your requirements.